# python package not importing after docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

When I run my docker-compose.yml file using `docker-compose up`, it outputs a ModuleNotFoundError for the boto3 package. Before running `docker-compose up` I ran `docker build .` using a Dockerfile that successfully pip installed boto3 from the requirements.txt file. So far i've only tried quitting and restarting Docker.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/airflow/
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Here's the error output for `docker-compose up`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 243, in process_file
webserver_1  |     m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
webserver_1  |     module = _load(spec)
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/stage_fact_dag.py", line 1, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from operators import (CreatedTableOperator, StageToRedshiftOperator, DataQualityOperator)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/operators/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from operators.stage_redshift import StageToRedshiftOperator
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/operators/stage_redshift.py", line 1, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_hook import AwsHook
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py", line 26, in <module>
webserver_1  |     import boto3
webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

Comment: How are referring DockerFile in docker-compose?

Comment: I didn't refer to DockerFile in the docker-compose. How should I?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs for the image you are using](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow#build), you can install additional requirements using build args

```
webserver:
  build:
    args:
      PYTHON_DEPS: "boto3"
```

Comment: I added your snippet and got the error: ```ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service webserver has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.```